# Double confirmation on exit

Tags: c#, winforms, exit, confirm

I am trying to make it so that the user is prompted to confirm exiting my program in c#, but for some reason, if they say "yes" they would like to exit, the confirmation box would pop up again. I can't figure out why.

```
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else { Application.Exit(); }
```

Comment: Where is this code being run?

Comment: I am assuming you are handling Form Close event.  I don't think you need Application.Exit()

Comment: Yes, form closing, but I do need application.exit() as there is another window open that I need to close at the same time.

Comment: In your Application.Run(), which form are you passing in?

Comment: StartupWindow(), and the window that is closing is BackupWindow(). I need both of them to close if one of them closes, so I found the easiest way to do that is to simply use Application.Exit().

Comment: I see... then Lambert got the answer for you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, did you check the `CloseReason` for the `FormClosing` event? I think you might get the same event for two different reasons (although I don't exactly expect that to happen normally); check your `FormClosingEventArgs` to see what the parameters are.

Answer (score 12):

Use this

```
 private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close?", "Infomate", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Ah, I figured out how to fix it. I removed the Application.Exit(); event from the FormClosing event, and moved it into the FormClosed event. It all works now.

Comment: I got the same weird issue as you and your answer solved it perfeclty.

Answer (score 1):

As SFD he said you need to create the event with the message box. I've added to filter if the user it's closing the form and a warning messagebox:

```
    private void close_confirmation(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close?", "Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

You nee to assign the event to the form to make it work:

```
this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(close_confirmation);
```

If you want to make it stop so the user can close again the window without the message:

```
this.FormClosing -= close_confirmation;
```